# Rating control not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am usinf .net framework 4.5. I need to make rating system for which I have user asp rating control. Now if I try to give rating behavior doesn't changed. Also I have 5 star rating but If I hover mouse on any star it will always shows tool tip 1. When I saw a developer tools in chrome this errors it shows
[image]

Please help me to fix this issue.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ratings.aspx.vb" Inherits="ratings" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .star {
            color: #f00;
            font-size:2em
        }

        .empty {
            color: #ccc;
            font-size:2em
        }

        .WaitingStar {
            color: #ed2025;
            font-size:2em
        }

        .FilledStar{
            color: #ffcc00;
            font-size:2em
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolKitScriptManager ID="sc1" runat="server"></asp:ToolKitScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:Rating ID="r1" runat="server" EmptyStarCssClass="fa fa-star empty" StarCssClass="fa fa-star empty" WaitingStarCssClass="fa fa-star WaitingStar" FilledStarCssClass="fa fa-star FilledStar" MaxRating="5" CurrentRating="1"></asp:Rating>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Global.asax(Default)

```
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Optimization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

    <script runat="server">

        Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
        End Sub
    </script>
```

Global.asax(Editted)

```
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Optimization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">
    Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.MapPageRoute("index", "index", "~/index.aspx")
        routes.MapPageRoute("cart", "cart", "~/cart.aspx")
        routes.MapPageRoute("search", "search/{searhWords}", "~/search.aspx")
        routes.MapPageRoute("allListing", "{type}", "~/all-listing.aspx")
        routes.MapPageRoute("allListing2", "all/{type}", "~/all-listing2.aspx")
        routes.MapPageRoute("priceRangeWise", "price-range/{price}", "~/price-range-wise.aspx")
        routes.MapPageRoute("skillPage", "skill/{categoryName}/{slug}/{productPageID}", "~/experience-page.aspx")
    End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with the code you have posted. Do you add any html or javascript dynamically?

Comment: @GaAd No. There is no additional script or anything else. You can also see live demo foxboxrewards.com/ratings.aspx

Comment: @GaAd can you tell me what those errors are there in developer tools? I am sure that is the cause of this problem

Comment: @GaAd All paths are correct in my css. Infect I found where is the actual issue. When I create new project in VS it has it's default Global.asax file. So I have changed it as per my requirements. Due to that it is not getting correct path of webResource.axd file which shown in developer tool. But I have to keep those changes in global.asax. Please review my default globa; asax & the one I have changed. I am posting in to my question

Comment: @GaAd No I just found the cause. Problem not solved yet. If you review my post again you will find 2 different global.asax files. I need to keep editted one for my project but in that rating control not working.

Comment: @GaAd Because I need to use dynamic page routing like this routes.MapPageRoute("skillPage", "skill/{categoryName}/{slug}/{productPageID}", "~/experience-page.aspx") I can not use default routing becuase then it won't find correct path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

Add this in your RegisterRoutes function
.axd files don't exist physically

Comment: It shows error IgnoreRoute is not member of Route Collection.

Comment: Can you import System.Web.Http in RouteConfig.vb?

Comment: I did but still that problem exist

Comment: Ok i can smell that something is wrong here. Microsoft sais that ingore route is under System.Web.Routing. See link below:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784609(v=vs.110).aspx

I cannot understand why you are getting this error.

Comment: Are you using MVC need more info about your project,

Comment: try routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

Comment: No I am not using MVC. It's Web Forms

Comment: Try routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

Comment: Thank you so much. routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); worked. Please update your answer so I can mark that as answer. Once again thanks.

Comment: Updated. No worries glad i helped!